# CARBON Get all dates between date range using number of the weekday

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I have an array that indicates the number of the weekday for example this array:

```
[1, 3, 5]
```

Indicates Monday, Wednesday and Friday, given a date range how can I get the date of all mondays, wednesdays and friday between that range.

I'm using Laravel with Carbon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this Code:

```
function weekDaysBetween($requiredDays, $start, $end){
    $startTime = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $start);
    $endTime = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $end);

    $result = [];

    while ($startTime->lt($endTime)) {
        
        if(in_array($startTime->dayOfWeek, $requiredDays)){
            array_push($result, $startTime->copy());
        }
        
        $startTime->addDay();
    }

    return $result;
}
```

And you can call it like:

```
weekDaysBetween([1,2, 3], "01-09-2021", "01-10-2021")
```

And the reult would be like:

```
[
    "2021-09-01T22:02:21.000000Z",
    "2021-09-06T22:02:21.000000Z",
    "2021-09-07T22:02:21.000000Z",
    "2021-09-08T22:02:21.000000Z",
    "2021-09-13T22:02:21.000000Z",
    "2021-09-14T22:02:21.000000Z",
    "2021-09-15T22:02:21.000000Z",
    "2021-09-20T22:02:21.000000Z",
    "2021-09-21T22:02:21.000000Z",
    "2021-09-22T22:02:21.000000Z",
    "2021-09-27T22:02:21.000000Z",
    "2021-09-28T22:02:21.000000Z",
    "2021-09-29T22:02:21.000000Z"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `->daysUntil()->filter()`

```php
function weekDaysBetween($requiredDays, $start, $end)
{
  return CarbonImmutable::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $start)
    ->daysUntil(CarbonImmutable::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $end))
    ->filter(static fn (CarbonImmutable $date) => in_array($date->dayOfWeek, $requiredDays, true));
}
```